# Set up auto provisioning for custom SAML Web app in Google workspace

Tags: saml, google-apps, google-workspace, provisioning, scim

I am trying to set up a custom SAML Web app with auto provisioning in my google admin. I am able to create an custom SAML Web app but the auto provisioning feature is not available. As per this community [link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7681608?hl=en) there are a bunch of other apps which provide auto provisioning. I couldn’t find a way to setup a custom one.

I am creating a custom SAML Web app by following steps:

1. Logging into google admin
2. App -> Web and Mobile Apps -> Add App -> Add custom SAML App

Below is how it looks after i create few apps already present in the apps list and when i create a custom SAML App. The custom app clearly does not have the User auto provisioning or there is a setting for the same which i am missing.

[image]

How do i set up auto provisioning for custom SAML Web app?
Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently there is no support for auto-provisioning on custom SAML apps. In their [release blog post](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2016/07/automatically-provision-users-with-scim.html) Google explains how this works:

> Following this launch, admins will be able to set up automated user provisioning and deprovisioning for Salesforce.com and other apps (with support for more applications coming soon).

These are apps that they are specifically adding support to. Since then they have been steadily [adding](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2018/03/automatically-provision-users-with-four.html) [more](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2019/08/automatically-provision-users-adobe-comeet-foodee-recog-spoke.html) [apps](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2019/01/automatically-provision-users-with-two.html) to their catalog, but it's still a predefined list. All SPs have different APIs to provision users so it is probably not so easy to create an interface that will be able to connect with any of them, so Google seems to be sticking to implementing them one by one.

The link that you shared contains another link to [Apps that support automated provisioning](https://support.google.com/a/topic/10018788), which has the full list of supported apps. Any app outside of this list won't have auto-provisioning available.